# Prevent Mp3 player (that runs inside an iFrame on our site) being embedded else where?

Tags: php, security, iframe, embed, hotlinking

We have an mp3 player that runs via an iFrame, not our choice but thats how we're stuck with it. We want to prevent other people simply embedding the iframe on their site.

What would be the best way to do this? We're running nginx so no .htaccess. The mp3 player is made up of php files and we need to keep running it in an iframe.

Is there anyway to lock the specific mp3 players php file (in this case html5player.php) to only be able to be executed on our server or domain name? Surely there is a way to do that in nginx? But then of course, if they embed the iFrame it will think it IS running on our server anyway wont it?

Everything solution I've thought of has fallen down somewhere along the way, so input much appreciated.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but why do you want to stop people promoting your site? If someone embeds your iframe they're endoersing your content. Just include a link to your site in the frame that says something like 'get more here' and essentially other people will be advertising for you.

Comment: Because its members only content - other sites would be stealing the player to give it away for free...

Comment: I suspect we have differing views on this but I'll share mine and let you mull it over. If your content is popular enough to be stolen think of that as a victory. Content sharing is a great way for new people to discover your content. If they love it, they'll pay for it.

Comment: No it means other websites steal the players we charge our members for to give away for free to get the traffic to their website (why pay when you can get it for free elsewhere?!) whist we're PAYING for them to do it in S3 server costs!

Comment: But if you charge your members for its use, I assume that the visitor / member must be logged in on your site to use the player so there really should be no problem, right? If not, you should make sure the user has to login to use it.

Comment: yes they have to log in to use it on our site, but think, its an iframe that causes the player to appear - which means the iframe can put onto any site once they log into ours and steal the link.

Comment: If your `html5player.php` starts with code to check if the visitor is logged in, no one will be able to use your iframe and show the player (unless a visitor is logged in at your site and visits the copying site but that would be a very rare exception...).

Comment: jeroen, is there a way to make it check if they are logged in on OUR site, because if someone is logged in, in wordpress, id imagine it would appear (seen as its just checking for "logged in".

Comment: I used one of the WP php headers to check for logged in users, it doesn't work because it doesn't even see logged in users on our site - again, iframe is probably to blame. The iframe is a NIGHTMARE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the URL of the parent window within the iframe, and check if it matches your domain or not... and then accordingly display the mp3 player or deny access.

use the following in the javascript inside the iframe:

```
if(top.location.href == "http://mysite.com"){
        //display mp3 player
        } 
//or don't display mp3 player
```